# asp:sqldatasource SelectCommandType="Text" Dropdown not populating ONLY when parameters are passed to SQL

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use a `asp:SqlDataSource` driven by a SQL Select with Arguments. It works as long as I don't have any arguments.  I can run the parameterized query via studio and it works and returns rows.  If I any arguments, then the `asp:View` doesn't render.

First, the code returns 2 rows when I execute the SQL via Studio.
Second, I don't want it as a stored proc.  Deployment issue.  Smile, let it go. :-)

---

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlGetCSGUsersOnClaim" DataTextField="username" DataValueField="userID" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGetCSGUsersOnClaim" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer%>" SelectCommandType="Text" SelectCommand="
SELECT aspnet_Users.UserId as userID, aspnet_users.username as username
FROM claims, aspnet_Users
WHERE claims.claimid = @ClaimID and 
(Claims.AdjusterID = aspnet_Users.UserId or Claims.SupervisorID = aspnet_Users.UserId )">
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter Name="ClaimID" SessionField="ClaimID" Type="Int32" DbType="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

---

If I remove the `@ClaimID` and `SelectParameters` arguments, the dropdown populates.  It only fails once I add the parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned that if I removed the Type and DBType attributes of the SelectParameter, the code worked.  sigh....

I have no idea, why though.